# Enable Migrations doesn't work in ASP MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

I am trying to enable migrations in my project but I always get this error :

> More than one context type was found in the assembly 'CarManagement'.
> To enable migrations for 'CarManagement.Models.CarManagementContext', use Enable-Migrations
>
> -ContextTypeName CarManagement.Models.CarManagementContext.
>
> To enable migrations for 'CarManagement.Models.ApplicationDbContext', use

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName CarManagement.Models.ApplicationDbContext
```

and when I try to use only one context it also does not work and this error appears:

> Enable-Migrations: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'CarManagement.Models.CarManagementContext.'.
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName eManager CarManagement.Models.CarM ...
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Enable-Migrations], ParameterBindingException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Enable-Migrations
>   ```

[image: screenshot of PM to embed]

Comment: Show your entire commandline. I think you have a rogue "eManager" somewhere in it.

Comment: PM> Enable-Migrations
More than one context type was found in the assembly 'CarManagement'.
To enable migrations for 'CarManagement.Models.CarManagementContext', use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName CarManagement.Models.CarManagementContext.
To enable migrations for 'CarManagement.Models.ApplicationDbContext', use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName CarManagement.Models.ApplicationDbContext.
PM> Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName eManager CarManagement.Models.CarManagementContext.
Enable-Migrations : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts ..........

Comment: Yeah that doesn't really help. Anyway remove the "eManager" from that.

Comment: Sorry I will try to take a screenshot, maybe you it will be more clear, what do you mean by eManager ? How can i remove it ?

Comment: You are using the commandline `Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName eManager CarManagement.Models.CarManagementContext`. Remove the "eManager" from that. I don't know where it comes from, but you have typed it.

Comment: I tried but still an error. This time is :
The context type 'CarManagement.Models.Voiture.' was not found in the assembly 'CarManagement'.

Comment: You really should read the errors more carefully. It explains very explicitly what you're doing wrong. :)

Comment: I am trying but sometimes I didnt understand anything ! anway it was an extra dot thats why it didnt work ! thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're typing a dot at the end of command. Try just:

`Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName CarManagement.Models.ApplicationDbContext`

Answer (score 10):

I was getting the same error when I was trying to add migration with `Add-Migration`.

[image]

The issue was, as I have had more than one `DBContext`, I had to specify which one to use. We can either use the '-Context' parameter for `PowerShell` commands or the '--context' parameter for `dotnet` commands.

I was using `--context` in my command instead of `-Context` as I was running the command in Package Manager Console.

```
Add-Migration "AddNameColumnFavorites" --context LearnraumDatabaseCon
```

To fix the issue, I had to change the command as preceding.

```
Add-Migration -Context LearnraumDatabaseContext "AddNameColumnFavorites"
```

Hope it helps.